# configure /etc/nginx/nginx.conf to redirect to separate host

Tags: redirect, ubuntu, nginx

Does anyone know how to modify the nginx.conf file to redirect to another host? I would like to direct http://mydomain.com/page1 and http://mydomain.com/page2 to separate hosts on my local network. mydomain.com/page1 should go to 10.100.0.163 and mydomain.com/page2 should go to 10.100.0.164.

Here is what I added to the HTML section of the nginx.conf file on my Ubuntu server.

```
location /page1/ {
rewrite ^/page1/(.*)$ http://10.100.0.163/$1 permanent;
}

location /page2/ {
rewrite ^/page2/(.*)$ http://10.100.0.164/$1 permanent;
}
```

Is there anything else I need to add to the nginx.conf file? Are there any other configuration files I also need to modify?

I just did a standard install of nginx and haven't changed anything else.

Comment: do you mean that it pulls the data from host B while still showing the url of host A? because if so, google "nginx reverse proxy"

Answer (score 8):

On Debian-based distributions (including Ubuntu) the following considerations are true for nginx (similar layout is used by the apache packages):

- `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` is the main config file
- the main config file includes all files in `/etc/nginx/conf.d` and `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`
- `/etc/nginx/conf.d/<some-file>` is where you put *additions to the main config*.

  - If any packages other then nginx add configuration those will be in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/<packagename>` (think packages like gitweb, or some php-thing).
  - Add a file `/etc/nginx/conf.d/local` or `/etc/nginx/conf.d/local_something` in there with any additions you need.
  - By sepparating things out like that it makes it easy to determine where any potential problems are.
- `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/<some-file>` is where you put the configuration *additions needed for virtual hosts*, 1 file per virtual host. By sepparating out the virtual hosts, it becomes easier to know where to look to change/fix things (as you know automatically ignore everyting not relevant to that vhost).
- `/etc/nginx/sites-available/` is where packages put config for vhosts they want to add. *These are not automatically active*, to enable such a site you'd link it from or copy it to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`

Since the additions you want to make are specific to the `mydomain.com`  virtual host, you should add them to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mydomain.com`. The contents of which should be something like this:

```
server{
  server_name mydomain.com;

  location /page1/ { rewrite ^/page1/(.*)$ $scheme://10.100.0.163/$1 permanent; }
  location /page2/ { rewrite ^/page2/(.*)$ $scheme://10.100.0.164/$1 permanent; }

  #add config needed to server whatever else on 
  #location / {}
}
```

Notes about that config:

- If you do it with a `rewrite` as above, *the url shown in the browser will be changed to the rewritten url automatically*.
- If you want the url shown to the user to remain "mydomain.com/page1", you need to use a [proxy_pass](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass)-directive instead of a rewrite (keyword for this kind of setup is *reverse proxy*)
- you use $scheme:// instead of $http:// as it won't break that way if you also have that vhost listen on https:// later on

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will create a file called 'mydomain.com' in the sites-enabled folder with the server function you suggest. Is this the only thing you suggest I do? Do I also need to add something to one of the other nginx configuration files so that it knows this virtual host exists?

Comment: if you look in the /etc/nginx/nginx.conf you'll notice it has the line `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;` that makes it pick up any file in the sites-enabled folder (note: nginx only notices changes to the configuration on restart or reload, so you do need to do `service nginx reload`). You don't need anything else for what you described